# HTTP GET request in java returns meaningless data from App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, get, put, httpconnection

I'm requesting a json file from an App Engine URL

http://1-1-26a.wordbuzzweb.appspot.com/json/level-images.json

The file encoding is UTF-8 without a BOM. If I look at this file on my local disk it's size is 12414 bytes. If I get the file in Chrome is reads it perfectly well. If I then save it it's 12414 bytes. However, if I try and download the file with a GET request in java I only get 780 bytes returned and the returned data would appear to be meaningless.

I've tried several different types of get request, both of the methods below I have used elsewhere perfectly effectively. The response code on the GET requests is 200. Interestingly, if I do a POST with no content instead of a GET, then I get the valid response.

If I download the file from [this](https://googledrive.com/host/0B9Hi1LzOUyXmfkVHNXB5VXFoZmdFMlFwS0tnRmViNEpiblNxdWdGc1I0SmpzRU1oTkMxQTg/level-images.json) URL on Google Drive instead, then the GET methods below work perfectly.

**edit** This code is now working, however, this is a recurring issue that comes and goes. If anyone has any ideas what might be causing it then please say so!

**This doesn't work**

```
public static String doGetSync(String urlToRead) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);

    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();

    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();

    return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

**Neither does this**

```
public static String doGetSync2(String urlToRead) throws IOException {
    final String charset = "UTF-8";
    // Create the connection
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlToRead).openConnection();

    // Check the error stream first, if this is null then there have been no issues with the request
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
    if (inputStream == null)
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    // Read everything from our stream
    BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    responseReader.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

**This code works**

```
public static String doPostSync(final String url, final String content) throws IOException {
    final String charset = "UTF-8";
    // Create the connection
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    // setDoOutput(true) implicitly set's the request type to POST
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

    // Write to the connection
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(content.getBytes(charset));
    output.close();

    // Check the error stream first, if this is null then there have been no issues with the request
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
    if (inputStream == null)
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    // Read everything from our stream
    BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    responseReader.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet works for me: I call it with given URL parameter and print it to console. Everything seems to be in place. BUFFER_SIZE was set to 4096.

Comment: @yozh Well that's very odd! That's the same BUFFER_SIZE I've got.

Comment: @yozh It's working fine for me now too - and I've changed nothing. I was about to try to apache commons lib instead. I've had this as a recurring issue that comes and goes for a few days. No idea what triggers it though.

Comment: For the record, the second one works for me.  Tried with and without adding the application/json header.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for that, how frustrating. I hate intermittent problems. I really can't release anything until I know this is resolved.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind right now is not closing connection in the first sample. Not sure if it would cause such issues though.